# Test case for views python

Tags: python, django

I am running a test case for this methon in my views.py

views.py

```
 69 def delete(request, activityId):
 70     """Delete activity form database
 71         Return to templates if the owner does not match the user
 72         otherwise, return to actuser:activity
 73     """
 74 
 75     activity = ActivityViewModel()
 76     activity.get_by_id(activityId)
 77     userName = activity.db.owner
 78 
 79     deleteThisActivity = activity.delete_from_actinbox(activity.db.owner, request.user.username)
 80 
 81     if deleteThisActivity == True:
 82         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('actuser:activity', args=(userName,)))
 83     else:
 84         activityForm = ActivityForm(instance=activity.db)
 85         return render(request, 'activity/profile.html', {
 86             'message': "You Are Not Allowed To Delete This Activity",
 87             'activity': activity.db,
 88             'form': activityForm,
 89            })
```

and this is my test but I am not sure how it would work.

tests.py

```
def test_activity_delete(self):
"""test activity that delete from database
"""
    delete_activity = create_activity(name="New Activity", userName="esutek")
    response = self.client.get(reverse('activity:delete', args=(delete_activity.pk,)))
    self.assertEqual(0, delete_activity)
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi, I just want to know how to right a test case for this. Is what I did right?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you your tests, using:

`self.assertIsInstance(response, HttpResponseRedirect)`

as your assertion?

Also, you will want to check that the activity was actually deleted:

```
val = Activity.get(delete_activity.pk)
self.assertEqual(val, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see when this thing will break; and then write your appropriate assert statements.

1. If there are no entries the database, what should it do?
2. If the entry doesn't match, the user, what should it do?
3. If the url is requested and the user is not logged in, what is the expected result?
   etc.

Lets take the second case; in this scenario the inputs to the test are:

1. `activity_id`, and a user that doesn't match the activity.
2. The correct result should be a response that contains the words *"You Are Not Allowed To Delete This Activity"*.

A sample test could be:

```
def test_delete_with_invalid_user_for_activity(self):
     c = self.client.login(username='another_user', password='sekret')
     u = User.objects.get(username='another_user')
     activity = Activity.objects.exclude(db.owner=u)[0]

     response = c.get(reverse('activity:delete', args=(activity.pk,)))
     self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
     self.assertEqual(response.context['message'],
                      'You Are Not Allowed To Delete This Activity')
     c.logout()
```